# Firefox Addon SDK - How to get a list of files in a directory, and get a file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the SDK to build a Firefox addon. In the addon options, the user can specify a directory of images for my addon to use (these will be added to a webpage).

I cannot figure out how to obtain a list of the files in the directory the user specified (Note that I know how to get this directory using `simple-prefs`). I also need to know how to get a specific file.

The file I get will be sent to a `contentScriptFile` to add to a webpage (as a `background-image`) using `pageMod`, via `worker.port.emit(...)`.

So my question: How do I obtain a list of files in a directory, and how to get one of those files to send to a `contentScriptFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out how to do it, using the Low-Level API [`io/file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file#mkpath%28path%29)

After you `require()` it using `var fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");` you can do the following:

- List files and directories in a directory using `fileIO.list(`*`path`*`)`, where *`path`* is the path to the directory
- Read a file using `fileIO.read(`*`path`*`)`, this returns a string with the contents of the file